# Can alternate universes (under Greene's Nine Multiverses Theory) exist with different matter and physics?

Tags: science-based, physics, alternate-reality, universe

So, it is clear I was not clear enough with the previous thing about "**handwavium**", so I will try this question again and be more frank. Although, the main subject has changed to an extent.

What I was thinking when I was referring to such exotic matter and physics at the time, was the possibility for parallel universes where, say... particles are either heavier or lighter than they would in our world, gravity works upside down, entropy is reversed, gravity is stronger than the other three forces, flat-out exotic particles that do not exist in our universe exist in the other, Lovecraftian biology, those kind of exotic matter and laws.

And when I was asking what kind of multiverse would allow that, I was referring to the ideas Greene had regarding the multiverse. Such universes with exotic physics has already been spoke of by Tegmark, and could fit his **Type II** to **IV** kind of multiverse.

However, I do not know how these kind of worlds would apply for **Greene's Nine Multiverses**. There has been the Quilted, Inflationary, Brane, Cyclic, Landscape, Quantum, Holographic, Simulated and Ultimate Multiverse. The Ultimate Multiverse can certainly allow this, so this leaves the remaining eight multiverses. Which ones amongst the eight can allow such worlds of exotic matter and altered physics?

In other words, when we unify Tegmark and Greene's theories together, which of Greene's multiverse would fit to which of Tegmark's four types?

Comment: If this is a rielaboration of your previous question, why haven't you edited it instead of posting it as new?

Comment: Name should be Brian Greene and I believe Max Tegmark hitched on the similar idea from Paul Dirac that nature(QM) speaks in math which was considered to be blasphemy back then and in this case a couple of models(I'm being conservative) too speaks of math we just need to look for them.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, Greene, not Green.

Comment: Oh yes, Dutch. That is because this question is not exactly wholly about handwavium anymore, but more on the multiverse theories that allow it. The main subject has changed a bit.

Comment: If those other realms can interact with ours, then they are not "other univeses", but parts of **the** universe. (And no, and far as we know such parts of the universe don't exist. But then our knowledge of physics *might* be fundamentally flawed.) If they cannot interact with us, then what does the word "exist" mean in this question?

Comment: My ideal universe allows multiverses to "exist", but I want to see which specific kind in Greene's theory allows the exotic things to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In other words, when we unify Tegmark and Green's theories together, which of Green's multiverse would fit to which of Tegmark's four types?**

Greene and Tegmark approach the concept of multiverse a bit differently. Tegmark's inflationary bubble multiverses are similar in concept to Greene's infinite inflation and landscape multiverse. Tegmark's many-worlds multiverse is the same many-worlds multiverse that Greene calls the quantum multiverse. Tegmark's infinite cosmic horizon is similar to Greene's quilted multiverse.

Tegmark, however applies the multiverse concept to four ways in which a multiverse scenario might be constructed. That is to say, he's not explicitly laying out a structure by which the multiverse is connected to our Universe for every scenario, but rather scenarios which would lead to multiverse constructs. Greene's are more specific, laying out a possible mathematical and physical connection that a multiverse might have with our Universe, with of course, assuming that string theory (now brane cosmology) is an appropriate way of characterizing our Universe.

**What I was thinking when I was referring to such exotic matter and physics at the time, was the possibility for parallel universes...**

The existence of other Universes is not a question of physics per se. If these other Universes have no direct physical connection with our Universe we could never observe them and they could never observe us. They could exist and their existence poses interesting philosophical questions, but this becomes a metaphysical rather than physical discussion.

Cosmologist are interested in the structure of our Universe and by extension, possible connections it may have to other Universes. Particularly, they are interested in exploring the physics and mathematics of anomalies and peculiarities which may be allowed, from our current understanding of the physical laws, to give rise to other universes or access thereto.

Greene and Tegmark, both being noted physicists having worked in Cosmology, certainly give plausible ways in which Multiverses could exist...with our current understanding of physics. In all likelihood, in a few hundred years, experts will not find their ideas plausible in light of new discoveries; particularly Greene's as his ideas are closely tied to brane cosmology. If on the other-hand, brane cosmology is further developed, and does end up being able to make accurate predictions for which the standard model is unable explain, his ideas will likely be seen as ahead of their time.

**Can alternate universes exist with different matter and physics?**

So to answer the question, yes! There is no ab initio reason that other universes cannot exist with different laws and physics. No current law of physics forbids other Universes from existing.

**[what about universes where]... particles are either heavier or lighter than they would in our world, gravity works upside down, entropy is reversed, gravity is stronger than the other three forces, flat-out exotic particles that do not exist in our universe exist in the other, Lovecraftian biology, those kind of exotic matter and laws.**

If different Universes exist, they certainly could have different laws. However, the universe is a complicated place. Change one (simple) thing, and it changes everything. See my answer [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/177615/can-you-exist-in-a-scaled-up-universe/177638#177638) about the "fined-tuned" property of the Universe. I see no reason why you couldn't have a Universe that is, say, Lovecraftian. But, like our Universe, it would have to be fined tuned to be so and this fine-tuning is well beyond any modern understanding of physics. It much more complicated than changing a single particles mass as this would in nearly all probability not create the Universe you want.